# Problems with XamlCompositionBrushBase in UWP C#

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I've made a acrylic brush clone in C#. It works perfectly when I've running it with battery saver is disabled before running app, but when I'm enabling the battery saver and running it again, it does not enabling transparency when I'm disabling the battery saver when app is running. The same is with transparency toggle in Settings menu in Windows. So there is any way to reload the brush when battery saver is disabled (for example) in running app?

Here is the code:

```
        bool isWindowed = BackgroundSource == CustomAcrylicBackgroundSource.Hostbackdrop;
        if (useFallback == false && (DefaultTheme.AdvancedEffectsEnabled && PowerManager.EnergySaverStatus != EnergySaverStatus.On)
            && !(UIViewSettings.GetForCurrentView().UserInteractionMode == UserInteractionMode.Touch && isWindowed))
        {
            ArithmeticCompositeEffect crossFadeEffect = new ArithmeticCompositeEffect
            {
                MultiplyAmount = 0f,
                Source1Amount = (float)TintOpacity,
                Source2Amount = 1 - (float)TintOpacity,
                Source1 = new ColorSourceEffect
                {
                    Color = TintColor
                },
                Source2 = new ArithmeticCompositeEffect
                {
                    MultiplyAmount = 0f,
                    Source1Amount = sc_noiseOpacity,
                    Source2Amount = 0.98f,
                    Source1 = new BorderEffect
                    {
                        Source = new CompositionEffectSourceParameter("image"),
                        ExtendX = CanvasEdgeBehavior.Wrap,
                        ExtendY = CanvasEdgeBehavior.Wrap,
                    },
                    Source2 = new BlendEffect
                    {
                        Mode = BlendEffectMode.Exclusion,
                        Foreground = new ColorSourceEffect
                        {
                            Color = Sc_exclusionColor
                        },
                        Background = new SaturationEffect
                        {
                            Saturation = sc_saturation,
                            Source = new GaussianBlurEffect
                            {
                                BlurAmount = sc_blurRadius,
                                BorderMode = EffectBorderMode.Hard,
                                Name = "Blur",
                                Optimization = EffectOptimization.Balanced,
                                Source = new CompositionEffectSourceParameter("source")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            CompositionEffectFactory effectFactory = compositor.CreateEffectFactory(crossFadeEffect);
            effectBrush = effectFactory.CreateBrush();

            LoadedImageSurface imagesurface = LoadedImageSurface.StartLoadFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///UnitedCodebase/Assets/NoiseAsset_256X256_PNG.png"));

            CompositionSurfaceBrush imagebrush = compositor.CreateSurfaceBrush(imagesurface);
            imagebrush.Stretch = CompositionStretch.None;
            effectBrush.SetSourceParameter("image", imagebrush);

            if (BackgroundSource == CustomAcrylicBackgroundSource.Hostbackdrop)
            {
                backdropBrush = compositor.CreateHostBackdropBrush();
            }
            else
            {
                backdropBrush = compositor.CreateBackdropBrush();
            }

            effectBrush.SetSourceParameter("source", backdropBrush);

            CompositionBrush = effectBrush;
        }
        else
        {
            CompositionBrush = compositor.CreateColorBrush(FallbackColor);
        }

    private void DisconnectAcryilicBrush()
    {
        if (backdropBrush != null)
        {
            backdropBrush.Dispose();
            backdropBrush = null;
        }

        if (CompositionBrush != null)
        {
            CompositionBrush.Dispose();
            CompositionBrush = null;
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
    protected override void OnConnected()
    {
        bool usingFallback;

        if (BackgroundSource == CustomAcrylicBackgroundSource.Hostbackdrop)
        {
            usingFallback = !CompositionCapabilities.GetForCurrentView().AreEffectsSupported();
        }
        else
        {
            usingFallback = !CompositionCapabilities.GetForCurrentView().AreEffectsFast();
        }

        ConnectAcrylicBrush(usingFallback);

        base.OnConnected();
    }


    protected override void OnDisconnected()
    {
        DisconnectAcryilicBrush();

        base.OnDisconnected();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> So there is any way to reload the brush when battery saver is disabled (for example) in running app?

I have to say that is not possible. The transparency effect is controlled by the system. When the transparency effect feature is disabled from the Settings page, all the transparency effects will not work.

This is also mentioned in this document: [Acrylic material](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/acrylic#transient-surfaces). From the red note, it says Rendering acrylic surfaces is GPU-intensive, which can increase device power consumption and shorten battery life. **Acrylic effects are automatically disabled when a device enters Battery Saver mode. Users can disable acrylic effects for all apps by turning off Transparency effects in Settings > Personalization > Colors.**

Comment: the thing is that the transparency perfectly works for BackdropBrush (no matter in what condition the app started, battery saver is enabled or not), but not for HostBackdropBrush. Transparency effects is enabled in system. Also there is not this problem in acrylic brushes made by MSFT.

Comment: In the [AcrylicBackgroundSource Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.acrylicbackgroundsource?view=winrt-22000), it mentions that Backdrop samples from the app content and HostBackdrop samples from the content behind the app window. When you disable the transparency effect, the HostBackdropBrush won't be able to get the content behind the app windows. That's why it doesn't work.

Comment: that enum doesn't matter, because my class have custom enum. If you're talking about AreEffectsSupported, than I've tried everything, removed the 'if' conditions, made other brush with GaussianBlurEffect, these didn't worked too. I think the issue may come from compositor.CreateHostBackdropBrush() function.

Comment: @10Develops It's the same for CreateHostBackdropBrush(), it samples the area immediately behind the visual where it is used. But when the transparency effect is disabled, you can't get that.

Comment: HostBackdropBrush's transparency is creating perfectly when battery saver is disabled before app launch. When app is running, if I enable the BS it disables transparency, as it should, when I disabling it, it enables transparency again. But the thing is that it does not creating transparency when I'm disabling the BS, enabled before app's launch. The question is how to solve this?